What does a far-field SPICE model for a 900 MHz antenna look like?
Without doing in-depth math for the EMI, I am trying to find a SPICE model for an antenna for a 900 MHz RFID system.   My primary interest is circuits and not antennas per se, and using ADS and other tools I have through license, I can do this modeling.  However, this makes it very difficult to share my work with others, as the work isn't reproducible without expensive software.   I'm trying to make something that'll call “student facing”, so people can reproduce my work for some papers and a class that I'm working on.
My current SPICE netlist just uses a transformer where I send “1 Watt” of energy to it and then attenuate the power at the transformer to represent a distance between the transponder and the RFID tag.  The weakness of this approach is that we have a perfect resonator, and it doesn't take into account loading of the antenna due to the circuits. I feel that there is some better way to do this, and I couldn't find anything in literature regarding the use of SPICE, so I thought to ask here.
In summary, my question is “How does one model a dipole antenna with SPICE where the distance can be tuned?”

I've looked hard in the past for a way of doing this and found nothing despite extensive searching.

@Andyaka I can probably do this as I'm sure that I can, but I hate to reproduce work.  SPICE isn't ideal for this work, which is likely why it hasn't been done, but it sure is accessible.

Does that accessible solution contain formulas for the antenna losses and equivalent radiation impedance (a complex number) when driven at frequencies other than the exact resonant frequency? Will that solution properly model how the radiation pattern changes with non-resonant frequencies? In other words, how far does your model need to go?

@Andyaka Basically, it doesn't need to worry about other frequencies.  The item of interest is related to the RFID tags where you get capacative loading based on design choices for your charge pump.  The "turn on" distance for these passive devices is what is of interest.  It's a nice way to show that "charge pump" efficiency is relative because you need enough energy to turn on the system.   Anyway, I was just hoping there's something "better", and it seems that I'll probably just have to make it

In the far field, the effect of (transfer or self-) impedance, or variation thereof due to relative placement, distance, etc., is minimal.  Assuming the antenna is a one-port, you don't get any spacial awareness through that port, so the antenna can be reduced to an RLC equivalent network (of constant (RLC) values), approximating its self-impedance to that port over whatever required frequency span.
Any incident signal, can be modeled as a voltage source in series with any non-degenerate branch in that network, or a current source in shunt across any non-degenerate nodes.  The exact placement only determines the gain / frequency response from source to port; to the extent the port amplitude can be calibrated or normalized, the placement (given the above limitations) is irrelevant.  Equally so, I would suggest placing the source at the port itself, since that calibration is the most trivial.
This suffices for modeling a receiver: some input signal is applied, and the rest of the system selects, amplifies and demodulates it.  Receivers are typically specified in terms of minimum input voltage or power level, and one can model this directly as such, if so desired.
If you wish to model more about the link itself (say. from one antenna to another), you can reduce the system to two ports, with a network between them.  If you need to express true phase (including real time delay), and parameterization will be challenging at best (SPICE is a hierarchical programming environment, but not a variable-macro or recursive one).  Delay network complexity also depends quadratically on delay and bandwidth; a broadband network spanning several wavelengths (at the minimum frequency) might already be impractical to simulate.  Conversely, if a narrow or single frequency model suffices, and true delay isn't a concern, then the transmission path can be reduced to a single complex number (transmission loss and phase).
This range of ideas is still a very trivial model of the system, and it's not clear how much insight one wishes to draw from it, or to convey to others.  If the mechanical environment is consistent (e.g. two antennas within a test chamber, on rigid and repeatable mountings, perhaps adjustable), one could characterize it and model the s-params of the system, perhaps even crafting an interpolation function with distance so the model can be parameterized.  (An s-param based model would likely be AC-only; time-domain equivalents tend to have poor implementations, e.g. DFT + convolution per timestep.)  If one wishes to include various mechanical effects (like fading due to orientation / polarization, reflection, diffraction off nearby objects, etc.), at the very least the amount of data that must be acquired and fitted grows geometrically with the number of variables, and any meaning in a SPICE model quickly disappears as a full-field simulation becomes much more effective.
Mind, you don't mention what you're ultimately trying to do here, so there may be important and relevant details missed by this exploration, or indeed completely wrong for some applications.  The best I can do is answer the question as written, assuming you aren't interested in anything deeper than exactly that.  And also that, given the loose, qualitative or superficial nature of the question, that an answer along similar lines will prove acceptable.

What I'm trying to do is give complete simulation schematics for previous work that I have done: http://2018.ieeerfid.org/files/2017/08/rfid2018_degnan.pdf  I have physical transponders that I have produced, and I have ICs that I have produced, so I wanted to "open source" my schematics and other things.  The only thing that is not representative is my antenna proxies.
